# Making leveraged trade in pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

hi i coded a strategy in pinescript
my goal is to test in the broad term
i use it with leveraged trades
I couldn't find a way to do leveraged trading in tradingview directly with code, and i cant add liquid feature
At the same time, I want to define things like the highest money and the least money with code, but I couldn't find a good source. Does anyone know such a source?

i tried directly on tw and i couldn't

> 

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © togarman74
//@version=5
strategy("Ema 21,89,200 strategy",overlay=true)
//Emalar
ema21 = ta.ema(close,21)
ema89 = ta.ema(close,89)
ema200 = ta.ema(close,200)
plot(ema21,color=color.yellow)
plot(ema89,color=color.green)
plot(ema200,color=color.red)
// emalar ile birinci sart olusturma
//Long birinci şart 
Longsart1 = ema21 > ema200
ema21yukariKesisimi= ta.crossover(close,ema89)
LongSart2 = Longsart1 and ema21yukariKesisimi
// short ikinci sart
Shortsart1 = ema21 < ema200
ema21asagiKesisimi= ta.crossunder(close,ema89)
ShortSart2 = Shortsart1 and ema21asagiKesisimi

LongEmaSart=LongSart2 or LongSart2[1]
ShortEmaSart = ShortSart2 or ShortSart2[1]
//X Trender indikatürü
short_l1 = input(5, title='Short - L1')
short_l2 = input(20, title='Short - L2')
short_l3 = input(15, title='Short - L3')
long_l1 = input(20, title='Long - L1')
long_l2 = input(15, title='Long - L2')
shortTermXtrender = ta.rsi(ta.ema(close, short_l1) - ta.ema(close, short_l2), short_l3) - 50
longTermXtrender = ta.rsi(ta.ema(close, long_l1), long_l2) - 50
shortXtrenderCol = shortTermXtrender > 0 ? shortTermXtrender > shortTermXtrender[1] ? color.lime : #228B22 : shortTermXtrender > shortTermXtrender[1] ? color.red : #8B0000
t3(src, len) =>
    xe1_1 = ta.ema(src, len)
    xe2_1 = ta.ema(xe1_1, len)
    xe3_1 = ta.ema(xe2_1, len)
    xe4_1 = ta.ema(xe3_1, len)
    xe5_1 = ta.ema(xe4_1, len)
    xe6_1 = ta.ema(xe5_1, len)
    b_1 = 0.7
    c1_1 = -b_1 * b_1 * b_1
    c2_1 = 3 * b_1 * b_1 + 3 * b_1 * b_1 * b_1
    c3_1 = -6 * b_1 * b_1 - 3 * b_1 - 3 * b_1 * b_1 * b_1
    c4_1 = 1 + 3 * b_1 + b_1 * b_1 * b_1 + 3 * b_1 * b_1
    nT3Average_1 = c1_1 * xe6_1 + c2_1 * xe5_1 + c3_1 * xe4_1 + c4_1 * xe3_1
    nT3Average_1

maShortTermXtrender = t3(shortTermXtrender, 5)
colShortTermXtrender = maShortTermXtrender > maShortTermXtrender[1] ? color.lime : color.red

XtrendBuy=maShortTermXtrender > maShortTermXtrender[1] and maShortTermXtrender[1] < maShortTermXtrender[2] ? maShortTermXtrender : na
XtrendSell=maShortTermXtrender < maShortTermXtrender[1] and maShortTermXtrender[1] > maShortTermXtrender[2] ? maShortTermXtrender : na

plotshape(LongEmaSart and XtrendBuy,title="Long Signal",style=shape.labelup,location=location.belowbar,color=color.green ,text="Buy",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny,display=display.pane)
plotshape(ShortSart2 and XtrendSell,title="Short Signal",style=shape.labeldown,location=location.abovebar,color=color.red ,text="Sell",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny,display=display.pane)

if LongEmaSart and XtrendBuy 
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)
//if 
//    strategy.close("Long")

//short
if ShortSart2 and XtrendSell
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)
//if 
//    strategy.close("Short")


TP = input.float(title="kar al", defval=0.60, step=0.1)/100
SL = input.float(title="zarar kes", defval=1)/100
long_kar_hedef = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+TP)
long_zarar_kes = strategy.position_avg_price * (1-SL)
short_kar_hedef = // This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © togarman74
//@version=5
strategy("Ema 21,89,200 strategy",overlay=true)
//Emalar
ema21 = ta.ema(close,21)
ema89 = ta.ema(close,89)
ema200 = ta.ema(close,200)
plot(ema21,color=color.yellow)
plot(ema89,color=color.green)
plot(ema200,color=color.red)
// emalar ile birinci sart olusturma
//Long birinci şart 
Longsart1 = ema21 > ema200
ema21yukariKesisimi= ta.crossover(close,ema89)
LongSart2 = Longsart1 and ema21yukariKesisimi
// short ikinci sart
Shortsart1 = ema21 < ema200
ema21asagiKesisimi= ta.crossunder(close,ema89)
ShortSart2 = Shortsart1 and ema21asagiKesisimi

LongEmaSart=LongSart2 or LongSart2[1]
ShortEmaSart = ShortSart2 or ShortSart2[1]
//X Trender indikatürü
short_l1 = input(5, title='Short - L1')
short_l2 = input(20, title='Short - L2')
short_l3 = input(15, title='Short - L3')
long_l1 = input(20, title='Long - L1')
long_l2 = input(15, title='Long - L2')
shortTermXtrender = ta.rsi(ta.ema(close, short_l1) - ta.ema(close, short_l2), short_l3) - 50
longTermXtrender = ta.rsi(ta.ema(close, long_l1), long_l2) - 50
shortXtrenderCol = shortTermXtrender > 0 ? shortTermXtrender > shortTermXtrender[1] ? color.lime : #228B22 : shortTermXtrender > shortTermXtrender[1] ? color.red : #8B0000
t3(src, len) =>
    xe1_1 = ta.ema(src, len)
    xe2_1 = ta.ema(xe1_1, len)
    xe3_1 = ta.ema(xe2_1, len)
    xe4_1 = ta.ema(xe3_1, len)
    xe5_1 = ta.ema(xe4_1, len)
    xe6_1 = ta.ema(xe5_1, len)
    b_1 = 0.7
    c1_1 = -b_1 * b_1 * b_1
    c2_1 = 3 * b_1 * b_1 + 3 * b_1 * b_1 * b_1
    c3_1 = -6 * b_1 * b_1 - 3 * b_1 - 3 * b_1 * b_1 * b_1
    c4_1 = 1 + 3 * b_1 + b_1 * b_1 * b_1 + 3 * b_1 * b_1
    nT3Average_1 = c1_1 * xe6_1 + c2_1 * xe5_1 + c3_1 * xe4_1 + c4_1 * xe3_1
    nT3Average_1

maShortTermXtrender = t3(shortTermXtrender, 5)
colShortTermXtrender = maShortTermXtrender > maShortTermXtrender[1] ? color.lime : color.red

XtrendBuy=maShortTermXtrender > maShortTermXtrender[1] and maShortTermXtrender[1] < maShortTermXtrender[2] ? maShortTermXtrender : na
XtrendSell=maShortTermXtrender < maShortTermXtrender[1] and maShortTermXtrender[1] > maShortTermXtrender[2] ? maShortTermXtrender : na

plotshape(LongEmaSart and XtrendBuy,title="Long Signal",style=shape.labelup,location=location.belowbar,color=color.green ,text="Buy",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny,display=display.pane)
plotshape(ShortSart2 and XtrendSell,title="Short Signal",style=shape.labeldown,location=location.abovebar,color=color.red ,text="Sell",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny,display=display.pane)

if LongEmaSart and XtrendBuy 
    strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long)
//if 
//    strategy.close("Long")

//short
if ShortSart2 and XtrendSell
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)
//if 
//    strategy.close("Short")


TP = input.float(title="kar al", defval=0.60, step=0.1)/100
SL = input.float(title="zarar kes", defval=1)/100
long_kar_hedef = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+TP)
long_zarar_kes = strategy.position_avg_price * (1-SL)
short_kar_hedef = strategy.position_avg_price * (1-TP)
short_zarar_kes = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+SL)
if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("LSL-LTP", stop=long_zarar_kes, limit=long_kar_hedef)
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit("SSL-STP", stop=short_zarar_kes, limit=short_kar_hedef).position_avg_price * (1-TP)
short_zarar_kes = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+SL)
if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("LSL-LTP", stop=long_zarar_kes, limit=long_kar_hedef)
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit("SSL-STP", stop=short_zarar_kes, limit=short_kar_hedef)
```

Comment: i've been struggling with this for over a month straight from a $1000 wallet

I couldn't find any code that would allow me to open trades like 10x 50x for 100 dollars all the time.

likewise, I couldn't find any code that allows me to operate within the selected date range.